# How to save User Id and Password with JWT token via Asynchronous Storage in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I am new in react-native.I just want to create login functionality via the JSON API and store the JWT token of the user ID and my app is able to login, but the problem is that when I exit the app after login, I get Then login again. I post the Authloading and login screen in my question. Please check my full code.Here is my initial Screen.

```
class AuthLoadingScreen extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.loadData();
  }
 render() {
  return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', }}>
    <ActivityIndicator />
    <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
  </View>
  );
 }
  loadData = async () => {         
 const isLoggedIn = await AsyncStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn')        
this.props.navigation.navigate(isLoggedIn != 'null' ? 'loginnavigator' : 'drawernavigator') }
 }
```

This is my Logion Screen

```
 class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
  TextInputEmail: '',
  TextInputPassword: '',
  };
 }

 CheckTextInput = async () => {
  console.log(this.state.TextInputEmail);
   let pattern = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
   if (this.state.TextInputEmail != '') {
   if (this.state.TextInputPassword != '') {
    if(pattern.test(this.state.TextInputEmail) === true){

        await fetch('http://104.197.28.169:3000/auth/login?', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         },
         body: JSON.stringify({
           email: this.state.TextInputEmail,
           password: this.state.TextInputPassword,

         })          
       }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
              if(responseJson.message === "user logged in successfully")
               {
                   alert('User login Successfully')
                   console.log('Token' , responseJson.token)

              AsyncStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn',responseJson.token);
                  this.props.navigation.navigate('drawernavigator');           
               }
               else{
                            alert(responseJson.message);
              }

             }).done()
    } else {
      alert('Invalid email Address')
    }
  }
  else alert('Please Enter Password');

 } else alert('Please Enter Email & Password');
};


 const LoginNavgation = createStackNavigator(
 { screen : Login, },
 {
 defaultNavigationOptions: {
  header: null,
 }
},
);
const mydrawer = createStackNavigator(
{ app: AppContainer },
{
defaultNavigationOptions: {
  header: null,
}
});
```

This is my navigation code.

```
  export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
 {
  AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
  loginnavigator: LoginNavgation ,
  drawernavigator: mydrawer,
 },
));
```

Comment: I can assume that the problem is here
isLoggedIn != 'null' ? 'loginnavigator' : 'drawernavigator'
you are checking wether the token you get is equal to the string 'null'. Im guessing this is not what you are intending

Comment: Yes the problem is here. But I can not solve this problem. Please provide any suggestions to solve this problem

Comment: try isLoggedIn ? 'loginnavigator' : 'drawernavigator'

Comment: Have you tried logging loggedIn in loadData function

Comment: no this "isLoggedIn ? 'loginnavigator' : 'drawernavigator' " code is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is this:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate(isLoggedIn != 'null' ? 'loginnavigator' : 'drawernavigator') }
```

Here you will be getting a token in isLogged which will be not equal to null and if it is not null than you need to show drawer navigator.

DO this:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate(isLoggedIn != 'null' ? 'drawernavigator' : 'loginnavigator') }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've already done it but my app has opened directly without login.

Comment: If you had stored your token than it should directly navigate to drawernavigator, if token is not present you need to show loginnavigator, isn't the thing you want.

Comment: when i tried like this
AsyncStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn',  '1'); 
after then
  this.props.navigation.navigate(isLoggedIn != '1' ? 'loginnavigator' : 'drawernavi') 

Actually this code is working to prevent repeated logins. But with the help of this code I cannot save the user token. I only want to save tokens from login.